# button action in UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app one UITableView is there. In table cell am placing two labels and one button. button height is equal to (label1+ label2) height. these are to display content. and button is for action. Here my problem is am not able to perform button action in all portion. only some part is working when clicking.

Here is the code am used to place the labels and buttons

```
artistButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0, 6.0, 170.0, 50.0)];
artistButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:artistButton];
[self.contentView addSubview:artistButton];

artistLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0, 6.0, 170.0, 27.0)];
artistLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
artistLabel1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.14 green:0.29 blue:0.42 alpha:1]; 
artistLabel1.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
artistLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:artistLabel1];

artistLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0,20.0, 170.0, 27.0)];
artistLabel2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
artistLabel2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
artistLabel2.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
artistLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:artistLabel2];
```

any one can help or suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u plz clarify this line : "button action in all portion"

Comment: do you need a button (does it trigger another action than touching the cell itself). You should use the tableView delegate (`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:`). If you need a button, you should create it using `[UIButton buttonWithType: type]`.

Comment: Looks like the labels are covering the button frame. Try setting the content of those two labels as button title. `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state; `. You can adjust the properties of this `titleLabel` to make the content appear in more than one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my question.
Because of size of the button and labels only it is not working.
Now am adjusted the width and length of button and labels its working fine.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Add Target action to this Button

```
artistButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0, 6.0, 170.0, 50.0)];
artistButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[artistButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(ArtistAction)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInSide];

[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:artistButton];
[self.contentView addSubview:artistButton];


-(void)ArtistAction
{
  NSLog("Test Artist Action");
}
```

Comment: am added action also. performing action but i placed two labels.but my problem is some part only action is performing.

Answer (score 0):

add one line before UIButton declaration..

```
artistButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

after that you can initialize your UIButton code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do realize that the frames you set are overlapping.
You do call `[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:artistButton];` but you add the button as a subview after so it will have no effect.
Also you add other subviews after adding the button and those will be placed above you button.

So just add the two labels first and then the button you should be able to click the button properly, though you labels will be under the button and not sure how much of them will be visible. Check the frames you are setting for the objects you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

Just use for your cell `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:` method.